# Insert and shift matrix n*n

Tags: algorithm

I have a matrix N*N.

I need to implement a function that gets num 0/1, insert it to matrix and check if there is row / col with all 1.

The insertion need to be at this order:
if the matrix look like:

```
0 1 0
1 1 0 
0 0 0
```

And we insert 1 so now to matrix look like:

```
1 0 1
0 1 1
0 0 0
```

İf now we insert 0 ,so the matrix looks like:

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
1 0 0
```

I have idea to do right shift to matrix and i will take o(n^2) time.

There are another ideas to implement the function that insert value (0/1) and check for row and col with all 1?

Thanks!

Comment: so what is the question here?

Comment: is there more efficient way? Maybe bitVector?

Comment: i doubt it can be reduced further from `O(n^2)`, But lets hope anybody else has better option to suggest you :)

Answer (score -1):

A matrix is commonly implemented as an array in memory, with each `(x,y)` location indexed as `x*w + y`, where `w` is the width of the array (`x` and `y` are zero-based).  Printing the array is as simple as inserting a new row after every `w` elements.

This makes an insert an `O(n)` operation.  Just shift every element over by one position in the array.

Comment: Total numbers of elements in that array u are talking about is `n^2` ,not ` n. So time complexity is not `O(n)` but `O(n^2)` of the algo which u just gave

Comment: I wrote `n` as the length of the array, which is `N*N` in the OP's question.  You're right, it's still an `O(N*N)` or `O(N^2)` operation.  Every element in the matrix must be updated.